# cvAdd exception in c++ using openCV library

Tags: opencv

I wrote this c++ code using openCV for anding operation, i also used bitwise_and and cvAnd but it didnt work. I'm sure that there is no syntax errors but when i run it it gives me an exception

the code:

```
IplImage* result1 = cvCreateImage( cvGetSize(v_plane), 8, 3 );

    cvAdd(h_plane, s_plane, result1,NULL);
```

Answer (score 0):

h_plane, s_plane, and result1 must ALL be of the same format.

- Same size
- Same depth
- Same number of channels

cvConvertImage() can be helpful here.